# R: how to apply which.closest to a series of vector

Tags: r

```
a <- c(10:1)
b <- c(2,4,8)
library(birk)
which.closest(a,b)
```

An error message occurred by the function `which.closest(a, b)`

```
In vec - x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

In this case, `b` can be only one vector. How can I use `which.closest` when `b` is a vector?

Comment: What package does `which.closest` come from? That doesn't appear to be a base R function.

Comment: It is from birk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, `b` can only be numeric. If you are trying to output 3 values, aka to find which is the closest value in `a` to each value in `b` then you should use `apply` or a similar function.

```
lapply(b, which.closest, vec=a)
#[[1]]
#[1] 9

#[[2]]
#[1] 7

#[[3]]
#[1] 3
```

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: try `lapply(b, which.closest, vec=a)`